# How to add external html,css,php,jequery file in genesis framwok?

Tags: wordpress

How can i add external html,css file in wordpress genesis framawork?  Firstly i want to add in my localhost.is it possible?I wish genesis expert will give this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to incorporate other files to a Wordpress site, you'll need FTP access to your hosting server. Then you'll want to upload the desired files to directory, and then link or call out to those files however you would generally call a file.

But I don't know what sort of access you have to the theme's .php files in Genesis Framework, because it appears to be a paid theme.

But if you can alter the .php files, if you're adding a new .css or .js file that all the pages need access to, add the call to those files in your header.php file.